# How to delete all files named as asd.xsd recursively from SVN repository on Windows

Tags: powershell, svn

Is there any easy command to  delete all the files that are called asd.xsd from repository recursively from SVN repository.

It is annoying to go inside each folder right click and select tortoise svn delete command.

There must a be a command to look for the all files named asd.xsd and delete them from repository.

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647337/svn-delete-with-wildcard There are solutions for both TortoiseSVN and PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`:

```
foreach($FilePath in (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\svn\repo" -Include "asd.xsd" -Recurse |Select-Object -ExpandProperty "FullName")){
    svn del $FilePath
}
```

The `FullName` property contains the path to the file in question

Comment: Do I need to replace the FullName with the path of asd.xsd file?

Comment: No, since we pipe the files found to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty "FullName"`, the `$FilePath` variable now contains the FullName/Path in question - only thing you need to do is replace `"C:\svn\repo"` with the path to your actual svn working directory